# Regular Expression to match compound words using only the first word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression in JS which will match the occurences of `box` and return the full compound word

Using the string:

```
the box which is contained within a box-wrap has a box-button
```

I would like to get:

```
[box, box-wrap, box-button]
```

Is this possible to match these words only using the string `box`?

This is what I have tried so far but it does not return the results I desire.

http://jsfiddle.net/w860xdme/

```
var str ='the box which is contained within a box-wrap has a box-button';
var regex = new RegExp('([\w-]*box[\w-]*)', 'g');
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=str.match(regex);
```

Comment: What you have tried yet? Showing your effort will encourage other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
([\w-]*box[\w-]*)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/kW7yE2/3)

---

Requested by comments, here is a working example in javascript:

```js
function my_search(word, sentence) {
    var pattern = new RegExp("([\\w-]*" + word + "[\\w-]*)", "gi");
    sentence.replace(pattern, function(match) {
        document.write(match + "<br>"); // here you can do what do you want
        return match;
    });
};


var phrase = "the box which is contained within a box-wrap " +
             "has a box-button. it is inbox...";


my_search("box", phrase);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! But when I apply it to my Javascript, it does not work. See my jsFiddle in the question.

Comment: Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w860xdme/1/) using directly `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=str.match(/(box[\w-]*)/g);`

Comment: That works nice! but I was hoping to pass the string as a parameter to the regex so I think I need to use `new RegExp()`

Comment: @KAD. Your fiddle differs from my regex-answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just throw this out there:

```
(box[\w-]*)+
```

Comment: It should work but in my jsFiddle it returns the results `box,box-w,box-`. I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex in JS:

```
var w = "box"
var re = new RegExp("\\b" + w + "\\S*");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM1sW7/2)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, note the 'W' is upper case.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

**\Wbox\W**

Comment: This will match the `box` part, but not the `wrap` and `button` part.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're wanting to use the [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex. Match is a string method that will take a regex as an argument and return an array containing matches.

```
var str = "your string that contains all of the words you're looking for";
var regex = /you(\S)*(?=\s)/g;
var returnedArray = str.match(regex);
//console.log(returnedArray) returns ['you', 'you\'re']
```